# Precompilation of JSPs fail when file is included

Tags: maven, jsp, weblogic12c, precompile, weblogic-maven-plugin

The problem is that the jsps that are included in other files fail to compile during precompilation because the necessary import statements exist only on the page that includes them. Is there a way to avoid compiling certain pages during appc goal of weblogic-maven-plugin or to make maven understand where the import statement is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. I renamed the problematic jsp to jsi in order to avoid compiling them.